# Regressão Múltipla com R

Tags: r

Eu tenho uma tabela com algumas colunas de fatores que variam com o passar do tempo. Com a regressão múltipla eu posso avaliar a influência de um grupo de fatores na variação de 1. Como posso fazer isso em R?

Comment: A pergunta não está clara, você que saber apenas como fazer uma regressão no R?

Comment: Sim, eu gostaria de saber como fazer a regressão múltipla no R e se possível, a linear também.

Comment: Você algum código que já tentou desenvolver ou esta tentando? Colaca ele na pergunta, vai melhorar o entendimento do pessoal e vão poder ajudar melhor.

Comment: É só você seguir o passo a passo da resposta abaixo do Carlos Cinelli. Segui os passos e consegui fazer perfeitamente os cálculos e obtive os dados que eu precisava.

Comment: [Nós nao fazemos o seu trabalho de graca](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/) . O que é que voce já tentou?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode rodar uma regressão no `R` usando a função `lm`. Usando a base `mtcars` que já vem no R como exemplo:

```
regressao <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)
```

Primeiramente passamos a para a função `lm` fórmula da regressão `mpg ~ cyl`  e em seguida a base de dados `data = mtcars`. A fórmula `mpg ~ cyl` significa que estamos regredindo a variável `mpg` (milhas por galão) contra a variável `cyl` (cilindradas), seria equivalente à equação mph = b0 + b1*cyl + e, e você está estimando os parâmetros b0 (constante) e b1 (coeficiente angular). O resultado da regressão foi salvo no objeto `regressao`.

Ao dar `summary` você vê os principais resultados da regressão:

```
summary(regressao)

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.9814 -2.1185  0.2217  1.0717  7.5186 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  37.8846     2.0738   18.27  < 2e-16 ***
cyl          -2.8758     0.3224   -8.92 6.11e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.206 on 30 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7262,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7171 
F-statistic: 79.56 on 1 and 30 DF,  p-value: 6.113e-10
```

Para fazer uma regressão múltipla, basta incluir mais variáveis após o `~`. Mais especificamente, o elemento à esquerda do `~` é a variável dependente (o seu y) e todas variáveis à direita do `~` são variáveis explicativas (os X). Por exemplo:

```
regressao_multipla <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + wt + hp , data = mtcars)
```

Aqui rodamos uma regressão com 4 variáveis explicativas: `cyl`, `disp`, `wt` e `hp`, todas no `data.frame` mtcars. Para ver os principais resultados, use `summary` novamente:

```
summary(regressao_multipla)
Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + disp + wt + hp, data = mtcars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.0562 -1.4636 -0.4281  1.2854  5.8269 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 40.82854    2.75747  14.807 1.76e-14 ***
cyl         -1.29332    0.65588  -1.972 0.058947 .  
disp         0.01160    0.01173   0.989 0.331386    
wt          -3.85390    1.01547  -3.795 0.000759 ***
hp          -0.02054    0.01215  -1.691 0.102379    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.513 on 27 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8486,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8262 
F-statistic: 37.84 on 4 and 27 DF,  p-value: 1.061e-10
```

Há diversas outras funções para trabalhar com regressões no R. O objeto que a função `lm` retorna é da classe `lm`, para você ter uma idéia dos métodos disponíveis para a classe você pode rodar `methods(class = "lm")`.

Comment: Nossa, muito obrigado pela explicação! Me ajudou muito!

Comment: Testei a função com uma base de dados que estou trabalhando e funcionou muito bem.