# Obter coeficientes "a" e "b" do Modelo de Regressão Linear em R

Tags: r

Em um modelo de Regressão Linear Simples - y = a + bx - nós temos o coeficiente angular "b" e o intercepto "a". Gostaria de saber como eu faço para obter esses coeficientes em R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vale a pena mencionar aqui também o pacote [broom](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/index.html) que facilita bastante obter os dados de uma regressão (estimativas, erro-padrão, estatística t, p-valor etc).

Por exemplo, para pegar os dados básicos dos coeficientes de uma regressão, use a função `tidy()`. Voltando ao exemplo do modelo com a base `mtcars`:

```
library(broom) # carrega pacote
regressao <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars) # roda regressão
info_coeficientes <- tidy(regressao) # pega informações dos coeficientes
```

O objeto `info_coeficientes` é um `data.frame` com a estimativa, erro-padrão, estatística t e p-valor para cada uma dos coeficientes, incluindo a constante:

```
info_coeficientes
         term estimate std.error statistic      p.value
1 (Intercept) 37.88458 2.0738436 18.267808 8.369155e-18
2         cyl -2.87579 0.3224089 -8.919699 6.112687e-10
```

Comment: Gostei dessa função! Apesar de apresentar um pouco menos informações que a função summary(), as informações que ela apresenta parecem ser um pouco mais claras. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 7):

Utilizando parte de uma [resposta publicada aqui no SO há alguns dias](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/219466/49033):

```
regressao <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)
coef(regressao)
(Intercept)         cyl 
   37.88458    -2.87579
```

Ou seja, basta usar o comando `coef` no objeto criado com os resultados da regressão. Caso queira utilizar estes valores em outros cálculos, é possível salvá-los em outros objetos dentro da tua sessão no R:

```
a <- coef(regressao)[1] 
b <- coef(regressao)[2]
```

Para obter informações mais completas, como por exemplo os testes de hipóteses associados aos coeficientes da regressão, o R^2 e demais estatísticas, utilize o comando `summary`:

```
summary(regressao)

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.9814 -2.1185  0.2217  1.0717  7.5186 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  37.8846     2.0738   18.27  < 2e-16 ***
cyl          -2.8758     0.3224   -8.92 6.11e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.206 on 30 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7262,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7171 
F-statistic: 79.56 on 1 and 30 DF,  p-value: 6.113e-10
```

Perceba que o `summary` informa, dentro da coluna `Estimate`, os valores dos coeficientes linear (`(Intercept)`) e angular (`cyl`) do modelo de regressão ajustado.

Comment: Aproveite para incluir a obtenção dos dados dos coeficientes para uso.
`a <- coef(regressao)[1]`
`b <- coef(regressao)[2]`

Comment: Agradeço por seu conhecimento Marcus!

Comment: Valeu pela dica Daniel!